# DataTrigger type to textbox/checkbox/

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, datatrigger

I have an ItemsControl in which I display different properties and values, with the name on one side and a TextBox on the other side. The ItemsSource is a collection of objects of a custom class, that has Name, Value and PropertyType properties (using reflections propertyinfo)

Now I would like to improve this by being able to detect whether the property is of type bool for example, which would display a checkbox instead of a textbox. Is this possible using a DataTrigger?

I got it semi-working using a Control of which I set the template to a textbox or checkbox according to the type, but when I try to "tab" to the next textbox or checkbox, it focuses the control that has the textbox/checkbox first, and only after another "tab" it focuses the containing textbox/checkbox/..

So if anybody know a solution for this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've had a similar problem recently where I wanted to show a TextBox in a control if a bool was false and a TextBlock in it's place if that bool was true. I put both the TextBox and the TextBlock where I wanted either to show. Then, I bound the Visible property of each to the boolean value. I can post code if you think this would be your sltn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the solution you already have and set the [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) property to false on the control that wrongly gets tab focus.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, how could I've not seen something that simple. Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTemplate to select different View based on Value property type.

View:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ArrayList Options { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Options = new ArrayList();
        Options.Add(new TextProperty());
        Options.Add(new BoolProperty());
    }

}

public class TextProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public TextProperty()
    {
        Name = "Name";
        Value = "Default";
    }
}

public class BoolProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public BoolProperty()
    {
        Name = "IsEnabled";
        Value = true;
    }
}
```